# Nicer URL for viewing category of posts?

Tags: categories, urls

At the moment to view a category of posts I have a url like

```
http://server/category/tag
```

Is there a way in wordpress I can do this as:

```
http://server/tag
```

Comment: Do you want to remove the `/category/` base from category archive url ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the `/category/` base from wordpress urls then I recommend that you use [WP No Catgeory base plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/)

> #### Quote from plugin discription -
>
> This plugin will completely remove the mandatory 'Category Base' from your category permalinks 
>   e.g. `myblog.com/category/my-category/` to `myblog.com/my-category/`